# Running MongoDB aggregations in parallel

Tags: mongodb

Currently I'm running aggregations against a collection containing user and event information. For example:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      client: ObjectId('507f1f77bcf86cd799439011'),
      location: 'UK'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The above is a big simplification, suffice to say there are around 20 different variables like `location` that can go into that `$match` statement. There are also sometimes additional steps between these two, which is why I'm using `$group` to do a count. (Rather than `count`)

Currently I have an index on the `client` field, but haven't created indexes (compound or otherwise) on the other fields. As there are so many other fields, I can't just create indexes on everything - it'll be too expensive.

**The problem:** This works great when a client has a small number of documents, but as the number grows, the aggregation has to scan over an ever-increasing number of docs. The index focuses the range down, but it's not enough.

---

### Idea

Create an additional variable called `p` (for partition), and create a compound index: `{ client: 1, p: 1 }`. `p` can be `1`-`n`.

Instead of running the pipeline above, run a similar pipeline `n` times: (for all possible values of `p`)

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      client: ObjectId('507f1f77bcf86cd799439011'),
      p: 1, // or 2, 3, etc
      location: 'UK'
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The results from all pipelines could then be merged on the application level.

Using this method, I could limit the number of scans that each query has to do, theoretically decreasing query time.

Taking this a step further, this `p` value could be used as the shard key, so in theory, the analytics queries could be run in parallel across multiple shards.

**Has anyone done anything like this before? I've found very little on the subject.**

Comment: You said this was a simplified example. Is the end goal of it to give you a count? If not, what is the goal? I dont think running the same query `n` times is going to be a good route. Its probably better to just tune your pipeline.

Comment: The goal could be to get a count, a list of docs, or run a further aggregation step summing up particular fields. The variables that can go into the $match step vary based on user input, but I can't create indexes for all of them - the pipeline is already tuned. With that in mind, is running the query n times now a good route? If not, why?

Comment: Using application logic to force performance out of the db, your creating an approach that is not scalable. What happens when the db grows more? Add more `p`s. Eventually you will end up in the same situation. The reason I asked about the end goal was that maybe.. aggregation is not the right tool for this job, maybe it is. Example above can be solved with .count(query). Mongo gets slow if your passing around more fields than is needed. For example collection.find({},{_id:1}) on 500k documents will come back instantly, because its not trying to retrieve the full document.

Comment: Agreed - answer above can be solved with `count`, maybe I should have stuck with that rather than use a pipeline (even though that's what we're using). As the db grows, adding more `p`s is exactly what I'm thinking of doing, yes. This obviously won't work ad infinitum, but I can't see us using more than 20 `p`s any time soon. With that in mind, each individual query will be faster, thus the overall "query" will be, no?

Comment: Personally, I dont think so. But what you can do is run a test and throw `.explain("executionStats")` at the end of your query and you will get the performance stats. If the query mils * 20 `p` plus whatever you need to combine the results is reasonable, then you should be good.

Comment: The queries will be run in parallel, so the total time is = max(query mils) + combination time. Will report back in a week or so with results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Early tests on this approach shows that it works **really, really well.** Running multiple `count` queries in parallel means that the "total query time" calculation is now:

```
total time = max(single query time) + combination time
```

I haven't tested this at major scale yet, but at mid-scale it's an absolute treat.

Brief stats about this test:

- Collection has 2.5m documents
- 200k of these documents have the `client` parameter I care about
- I'm running 4 queries in parallel, each looking at a different subset (~50k) of documents

For small numbers of scans, there is almost no benefit to this approach. However for the above example, we're getting `total time` decreases of between **2-4x**.

It looks like there's a sweet spot for this approach between 50-100k subset size.

And of course, running tons of queries in parallel makes you potentially subject to other MongoDB limitations.